# Diagonalization and linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, diagonalization

I have $\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{V} \mathbf{u}(t)$.

Now I have to show that $\mathbf{x}'(t) = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}(t)$ implies that $\mathbf{u}'(t) = \mathbf{D} \mathbf{u}(t)$.

How do I do this?

I think I should use that
$$
\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{V} \mathbf{u}(t) \Leftrightarrow \mathbf{u}(t) = \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{x}(t)
$$
and that the diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$ is defined as
$$
\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{V} \Leftrightarrow \mathbf{V}^{-1} = \mathbf{D} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{-1}.
$$
and insert $\mathbf{V}^{-1}$ in $\mathbf{u}(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: by using $x(t) = V u(t)$ ($V$ constant matrix) and the fact that $x(t)$ satisfies the differential equatin $x'(t) = A x(t)$, you have

\begin{equation*}
Vu'(t) = x'(t) = A x(t) = AV u(t)
\end{equation*}
hence
\begin{equation*}
u'(t) = V^{-1}AV u(t)
\end{equation*}

Since the diagonal matrix $D$ is given by $V^{-1} A V$ you are done.

Comment: So you are finding the derivative of $x(t) = V u(t)$ which is $x'(t) = V u'(t)$ because $V$ is just constants?

Comment: Yes, $x(t)$ and $u(t)$ are just vectors: $x'(t)$ is just the derivative of every component of $x(t)$. By writing $(V)_{ij} = v_{ij}$,  the relation $x(t) = V u(t)$ tells us that

\begin{equation*}
x_i(t) = \sum_j v_{ij} u_j(t)
\end{equation*}
with each $v_{ij}$ constant. Now take the derivative of this and you get the relation of vectors $x'(t) = V u'(t)$.